# Can professionals with part time affiliate income opt for Section 44AD and Section 44ADA?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, india

Can Indian professionals (Software Engineer) who also earn from online affiliate income like Amazon claim for presumptive income tax scheme like section 44AD or section 44ADA?

Under seciton 44AD, the affiliate income can be shown as 8% only instead of 100%.
Under seciton 44ADA, the affiliate income can be shown as 50% only instead of 100%.

Would like to know how to decide the eligibility for sections 44AD and 44ADA. Ofcourse section 44AD sounds way too good.